# Base64 String Encoding C# vs TSQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, base64

I have base64 string encoding/decoding functions in C# and TSQL, my problem is encoded result from C# differs from encoding result in TSQL.

My goal is:

1. C# encoded string should be decoded in TSQL and vice-versa
2. Both functions should have an ability to encode/decode unicode characters

**C#**

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));

Result: dGVzdA==
```

**TSQL**

```
SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   Base64Encoding
FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST(N'test' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS bin
) AS bin_sql_server_temp

Result: dABlAHMAdAA=
```

Any idea how to match the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server is using UTF-16. Your C# code is using UTF-8, hence the difference.

To get the C# code to use UTF-16, you can do this:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("test"))

Result: dABlAHMAdAA=
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, your solution worked as expected and now I have clear understanding of why it works well.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desire result Use below TSQL

```
SELECT CAST('test' as varbinary(max)) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64
```

Comment: Except 'test' is not unicode. If you change that to N'test' - you will again get the same result as in question.

Comment: @ChiragMM From the question: "My goal is: [...] Both functions should have an ability to encode/decode unicode characters," so it looks like it *must* be Unicode.